# Blacklist [good]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, tag-blacklist

We have a [good](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/good) tag! Only two questions so far, the second one [appeared today](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/128321/how-do-i-get-the-whole-picture).

Let's just get rid of it, sooner than later.

Answer (score 5):

There are now no questions with that tag.

Only high(ish) rep users will be able to recreate it now, but it is a good candidate for blacklisting.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little vague on the details, should I leave the question open until it gets a status-completed/declined from one of the devs, since what I really want is blacklisting?

Comment: @YannisRizos - yes